# Can Unity 5 or Unreal Engine 4 do computationally identical physics simulation across platforms?

Tags: unity, physics, multiplayer, unreal-4

In order to use certain approaches to multiplayer physics, it requires that the clients calculate exactly the same values for physics simulations. That "exactly" is a very big word here and goes all the way down to the hardware.

Can Unity 5 or Unreal Engine 4 physics engines guarantee numerically exact physics simulations across platforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

And there is *rarely* a need for exact physics replication.

You mention multiplayer in your tags.

Generally, in a multiplayer game, the physics and game logic is performed by *one* instance, which can be the server hosting the game, or one of the client that hosts the game.

Each simulation step, that authority, the *server*, performs logic update and physics update then send the resulting game state to all of the *clients*. The clients draw the scene upon reception of these events.

This way, all of the clients do not need to compute physics, they only draw. This removes a load from the clients, and it allows every one to have the same simulation. Plus it helps against cheating!

Game clients still can simulate physics for:

1. estimating and predicting game behaviour
2. non-game logic behaviour; e.g.: rag doll, objects destruction

Answer (score 1):

**No.** What would be the point of that?

The physics simulation in a game engine is not a *real* simulation in the sense that everything is done with the correct real-world formulas and reproducible. Doing so would require massively more computing power.

Most of the time, you can't even exactly reproduce the same physics simulation in a game twice in a row.

**Edit:**
This of course depends on the exact implementation, but I just checked in the unreal engine and this is the result of repeating the same drop of a cube on a sphere (sorry for the bad image quality):

[image]

All four screenshots were taken from the same perspective. As you can see, sometimes the cube bounces far away, sometimes it stays close.

Comment: Please explain:
Most of the time, you can't even exactly reproduce the same physics simulation in a game twice in a row.

Comment: The physics calculations use a lot of randomness, e.g. when determining the angle an object bounces off after a collision. So, when you set up an experiment in your engine by dropping a cube on a sphere the cube will most likely fly off in a different direction every time you repeat the experiment.

Comment: @TheBrain, is it actual randomness, or is it merely a chaotic situation?

Comment: @TheBrain tested, and your assumption is incorrect

Comment: What's random in physics? Physics simulation is an exact science. The differences you get in simulating it in a game engine come from the fact that there may be small difference in time/frame and floating point calculations.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt That was my point exactly. Small disturbances in the tick time (which are random) can lead to very different results. Also, using a PRNG instead of the exact science approach is often preferrable for performance, e.g. with particle and fluid simulations.

Comment: @TheBrain Ah, I see your point.

Comment: I think the "randomness" is not caused by disturbances in the tick time but it's a feature of the Physics engine. It's an easy way how to simulate chaos without actually computing it :)